# I need to get the files name from the server using FTP in spring integration could anyone give the solution?

Tags: ftp, spring-integration

How to get the files name from the server , I need to check what are all the files presented in the server folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RemoteFileTemplate` is for you on the matter:

```
/**
 * List the files at the remote path.
 * @param path the path.
 * @return the list.
 */
F[] list(String path);
```

In case of FTP it delegates to the `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles()`.

Although yes, you can use that `FTPClient` directly for such an operation.

You also can try `DefaultFtpSessionFactory` and `getSession().listNames(path)`.

Comment: There is a subclass `FtpRemoteFileTemplate`. You can also use an [outbound gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound-gateway) with the `ls` command.